# Autocomplete Combobox displaying only matching data below

Tags: java

I want to create an autocomplete combobox in java and basically, I want to have an auto-complete or a list of suggestions filtered from mysql database regarding to the users input in the textfield. As the user types in the textfield, a list of suggestions appear below. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you mean autocomplete like that one when we type on google search ? well that's hard dude , provide some codes and I'll try to help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post code that you have tried yourself, and ask question based on issues (if any) you are facing. Refer - [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fev and Mandar for your responses. I managed to do it as shown below and hoping this will help someone else out there.

in the constructor add a keylistener to the combobox editor component. The typed text now the search keywords are used by this line of code 'dbutils.checker.getList(txt)' and the return type is the new model having the results of the search.

```
public mainWindow() {
        initComponents();
        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setEditable(true);
        comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
                String txt = comboBox.getEditor().getItem().toString();
                if (evt.getKeyCode() >= 65 && evt.getKeyCode() <= 90 || evt.getKeyCode() >= 96 && evt.getKeyCode() <= 105 || evt.getKeyCode() == 8) {
                    comboBox.setModel(dbutils.checker.getList(txt));
                    if (comboBox.getItemCount() > 0) {
                        comboBox.showPopup();
                        if (evt.getKeyCode() != 8) {
                            ((JTextComponent) comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).select(txt.length(), comboBox.getEditor().getItem().toString().length());
                        }else{
                            comboBox.getEditor().setItem(txt);
                        }
                    }else{
                        comboBox.addItem(txt);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }



public static DefaultComboBoxModel getList(String tosearch) {
        dbutils.checker.connect_to_db_again_again();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

        try {
            sqlcommand = "SELECT Product_Name FROM products where Product_Name like '%" + tosearch + "%' ORDER BY Product_Name ASC";
            rset = stmts.executeQuery(sqlcommand);

            while (rset.next()){
               model.addElement(rset.getString("Product_Name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(checker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



        return model;
    }
```

and now since i am using the combobox in a jtable i pass it as below.

```
 DefaultCellEditor editoritems = new DefaultCellEditor(mainWindow.comboBox);
                                    items.setCellEditor(editoritems);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that though in development environment, the latency in hitting the db may not have any implications, in a production where the client app and the db are in different locations, the latency may have implications on performance and usability. Also better to use DocumentListener rather than KeyListener for text components.